# fragment tabs crashes when change orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments

Error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.basket/com.example.basket.MainActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.basket.MainActivity$TabContentFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Fragment Class:

```
public class TabContentFragment extends Fragment {
    public TabContentFragment()
    {

    }
    private String mText;
    public TabContentFragment(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_tab_content,                  container, false);                     
        mlistView= (ListView) fragView.findViewById(R.id.postListView); 
        getData(mText);
        return fragView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that fragment an inner class?  If so you will need to make that inner class static.

See here:
[Unable to instantiate fragment make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276088/unable-to-instantiate-fragment-make-sure-class-name-exists-is-public-and-has-a)